# How than I show that this map is continuous?

Tags: continuity, cantor-set

I have the following problem:

> Consider the set $M=\{0,2\}^\mathbb{N}$ and the map $f:M\rightarrow C$ where C is the Cantor set such that $f(a)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{3^n}$ and show that f is continuous.

I somehow have no idea how to show this because I can't work with open sets, do I?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What topology do you assume for $M$?

Comment: oh sorry the discrete one

Comment: What is $a$? $a=(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$?

Comment: I have no more information about a, but I think yes it should be this one.

Comment: Could you help me out maybe?

Comment: You can already answer your own question and write an answer: with a discrete topology, every set is open...

Comment: So can I only say that the preimage of every set in $C$ is open, more precisly this holds for all open sets in $C$ and therefore f is continuous?

Comment: You got it. $       $

Comment: ah perfect thanks

Comment: May I suggest you write it into an answer?

Comment: Yes I'll do it in a view minutes, since I'm bit in hurry with my current work, sorry

Comment: no worries. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Together with @Louis Pan I remarked that on M we have the discrete topology, i.e. every set is open. So we can say that the preimage of every set in $C$ is open, more precisly this holds for all open sets in $C$, therefore $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Are you sure the topology on $M$ is not the product topology? This makes way more sense.

Comment: Ah whait, so the original task sounds like: Consider the cartesian product M of countably many copies of the discrete topological space with two points $\{0,2\}$…. Does this mean, that we use the product topology? So if you are right, what I think, then how can I prove it then wir the product topology because I have some problems to show somethin with the product topology

Comment: It's the product topology then. What definition of continuity do you know?

Comment: the one with open sets

Answer (score 1):

It followed from the discussion in the comments that $\{ 0, 2 \}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is to be equipped with the standard product topology.

Sketch: first show that sets of the form $\left[ \frac{k}{3^n}, \frac{k+1}{3^n} \right] \cap C$, where $k = \sum \limits_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{3^i}$ for some $a_i \in \{ 0, 2 \}$, form a basis of the Cantor set. So it suffices to check that the preimages of these sets through $f$ are open in $\{ 0, 2 \}^{\mathbb{N}}$. Then prove that if $k = \sum \limits_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{3^i}$, then

$$f^{-1} \left[ \left[ \tfrac{k}{3^n}, \tfrac{k+1}{3^n} \right] \cap C \right] = \left\{ (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \{ 0, 2 \}^{\mathbb{N}} : \bigwedge_{i=1}^n x_i = a_i \right\} $$

which by definition is open in $\{ 0, 2 \}^{\mathbb{N}}$, so it will finish the proof.